# Simple rasterizer producing incorrect ppm file

Tags: c++, ppm, rasterizing

Ive been using a guide provided by ScratchAPixel to implement a simple rasterizer that produces a PPM file. When I execute the code (copy and pasted) my output image is different to theirs. It almost looks corrupt. Does anyone else get a different output?

[Their output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqVTe.png)

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzCHM.png)

```
// c++ -o raster2d raster2d.cpp
// (c) www.scratchapixel.com

#include <cstdio> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <fstream> 

typedef float Vec2[2]; 
typedef float Vec3[3]; 
typedef unsigned char Rgb[3]; 

inline 
float edgeFunction(const Vec2 &a, const Vec2 &b, const Vec2 &c) 
{ return (c[0] - a[0]) * (b[1] - a[1]) - (c[1] - a[1]) * (b[0] - a[0]); } 

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    Vec2 v0 = {491.407, 411.407}; 
    Vec2 v1 = {148.593, 68.5928}; 
    Vec2 v2 = {148.593, 411.407}; 
    Vec3 c0 = {1, 0, 0}; 
    Vec3 c1 = {0, 1, 0}; 
    Vec3 c2 = {0, 0, 1}; 

    const uint32_t w = 512; 
    const uint32_t h = 512; 

    Rgb *framebuffer = new Rgb[w * h]; 
    memset(framebuffer, 0x0, w * h * 3); 

    float area = edgeFunction(v0, v1, v2); 

    for (uint32_t j = 0; j < h; ++j) { 
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < w; ++i) { 
            Vec2 p = {i + 0.5f, j + 0.5f}; 
            float w0 = edgeFunction(v1, v2, p); 
            float w1 = edgeFunction(v2, v0, p); 
            float w2 = edgeFunction(v0, v1, p); 
            if (w0 >= 0 && w1 >= 0 && w2 >= 0) { 
                w0 /= area; 
                w1 /= area; 
                w2 /= area; 
                float r = w0 * c0[0] + w1 * c1[0] + w2 * c2[0]; 
                float g = w0 * c0[1] + w1 * c1[1] + w2 * c2[1]; 
                float b = w0 * c0[2] + w1 * c1[2] + w2 * c2[2]; 
                framebuffer[j * w + i][0] = (unsigned char)(r * 255); 
                framebuffer[j * w + i][1] = (unsigned char)(g * 255); 
                framebuffer[j * w + i][2] = (unsigned char)(b * 255); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    std::ofstream ofs; 
    ofs.open("./raster2d.ppm"); 
    ofs << "P6\n" << w << " " << h << "\n255\n"; 
    ofs.write((char*)framebuffer, w * h * 3); 
    ofs.close(); 

    delete [] framebuffer; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Did you cut and paste this from one of their resources? If yes, did you change anything? If yes, examine what you changed and mark it in the question so we have a better idea of where we should start looking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ (Visual Studio), Can't write the number '10' to file, all other numbers working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972815/c-visual-studio-cant-write-the-number-10-to-file-all-other-numbers-work)

Comment: It almost looks corrupted! It **is** corrupted because you are running Windows which feels free to add carriage returns in your files. Open the file in **binary** mode.

Comment: How did you get on with my suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I am learning things on scratchapixel.com too and I have encountered the same issue as you did.
What you need to do is to open the file in binary mode.

```
ofs.open("./raster2d.ppm", std::ios::binary);
```

I want to thank @Mark Setchell from the comments, who gave the answer!